# Failing Rspec only with Zeus with undefined method for existing field declared with Mongoid using STI design pattern

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, sti, mongoid3, zeus

Using Rails 4, Zeus 0.13.3, rspec-rails edge and mongoid edge

Simple STI model:

File `my_model.rb` in `/model` directory

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :my_field
end
```

File `my_sti.rb` in `/model/my_model` directory

```
class MyModel
  class MySti << ::MyModel

    field :some_other_field
  end
end
```

Everything works as expected in console and web. When I run the spec via bundler:

> bundle exec rspec spec

It'all good, but the issue is when I run them with `zeus`, it throws:

> `<class:MySti>': undefined method`field' for MyModel::MySti:Class (NoMethodError)

2 ways of getting around the issue that I found so far:

- commenting the `field` declaration in the STI, specs are running fine, but obviously business logic is not!
- re-adding the `include Mongoid::Document` definition in the `MySti` class: spec and logic works fine with that, but I should not have to do that, and I am weary of possible unintended consequences of doing that.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Experiencing the same thing. Bump.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding a delegate work?

from documentation

```
class Greeter < ActiveRecord::Base
  def hello
    'hello'
  end

  def goodbye
    'goodbye'
  end
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :greeter
  delegate :hello, to: :greeter
end

Foo.new.hello   # => "hello"
Foo.new.goodbye # => NoMethodError:
```